# Clarification over an ambiguity in regards to the definition of functions.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

I have recently watched a couple of lectures in order to revise some of the notions that I will have to tackle in the coming months, and as I did so I have stumbled over something which baffled me a tad.

Now, within these lectures the lecturer described a relation as being a function solely *if it maps one element from the domain to one sole, unique element from the codomain* (or range assuming it is a surjective function we are dealing with); I found this a tad confusing since, ever since I can remember we considered functions to map a value from the domain to one sole value from the codomain/range, and if no value from the domain is mapped multiple times to the same value within the codomain/range then it is injective, hence abiding to the lecture's definition of a function.

Have I been missing something, do people automatically discard non-bijective, or at least non-injective functions for whatever reason?

Comment: No, we definitely care about non-bijective (including non-injective (and often also non-surjective)) functions. You seem to be confusing the definition of injectivity of a function with the definition of a function itself.

Comment: Could be, I mean as I stated to me a function is any mapping which takes one value from the domain and maps it to one value from the codomain/range, whereas in the lectures I mentioned there is the notion of uniqueness of the value to which the element from the domain is mapped to, leading me to believe that the person in question was solely referring to functions which are already injective, since he enforced upon the elements to be distinct.

Comment: Presumably the lecturer is trying to say that a function must be single valued, ie, it cannot map an $x$ to more than one $y.$ Even the most non injective function $f\equiv 1$ satisfies that requirement in a marvellous way.

Comment: The word "unique" here is confusing and ambiguous and the lecturer shouldn't have used it. The intended meaning is that $f(x)$ should have an unambiguous value, but that value could be the same as $f(y)$ for some $y \neq x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X,Y$ be sets and $\Gamma\subset X\times Y$ a subset. We call such a subset a relation from $X$ into $Y$. We then make the following standard definitions:

- $\text{dom}(\Gamma)=\{x\in X\,:\,\text{there is a $y\in Y$ such that $(x,y)\in \Gamma$}\}$, called the *domain* of $\Gamma$.
- $\text{im}(\Gamma)=\{y\in Y\,:\,\text{there is an $x\in X$ such that $(x,y)\in \Gamma$}\}$, called the *image* of $\Gamma$ (some people also call it the range of $\Gamma$, but I’d avoid this term because it is also sometimes used to refer to $Y$).
- We say $\Gamma$ is a *function* if for all $x\in X$, and all $y_1,y_2\in Y$, we have the implication
  \begin{align}
  \bigg((x,y_1)\in\Gamma\quad\text{and}\quad(x,y_2)\in\Gamma\bigg)\implies y_1=y_2.
  \end{align}
- Suppose $\Gamma$ is a function. We say it is *injective* if for all $x_1,x_2\in X$ and all $y\in Y$, we have the implication
  \begin{align}
  \bigg((x_1,y)\in\Gamma\quad\text{and}\quad(x_2,y)\in\Gamma\bigg)\implies x_1=x_2.
  \end{align}

---

Here are some equivalent ways of saying things.

- $\Gamma$ is a *function* if and only if for all $x\in X$, there is at-most one $y\in Y$ such that $(x,y)\in \Gamma$.
- $\Gamma$ is a *function* if and only if for all $x\in\text{dom}(\Gamma)$, there is a unique $y\in Y$ such that $(x,y)\in\Gamma$.
- Suppose $\Gamma$ is a function. Then, $\Gamma$ is injective if and only if for all $y\in Y$, there is at-most one $x\in X$ such that $(x,y)\in\Gamma$.
- Suppose $\Gamma$ is a function. Then, $\Gamma$ is injective if and only if for all $y\in\text{im}(\Gamma)$ there is a unique $x\in X$ (which necessarily belongs to $\text{dom}(\Gamma)$) such that $(x,y)\in\Gamma$.

---

So, you see the uniqueness is referring to different things. In the definition of *function*, the uniqueness is referring to the value in the codomain, i.e what happens in $Y$. In the definition of *injectivity* for functions, the uniqueness is referring to the domain, i.e what happens in $X$.

Comment: ok there are a bunch of other subtle remarks to be made about whether a relation refers to something defined on all of $X$, or whether we call $\Gamma$ the graph of a relation/function etc, and whether we should actually define relations/functions to be the triple $(X,Y,\Gamma)$ rather than just $\Gamma$, and so on, but these semantics/details can easily be figured out from context to context once you get the basic idea down.